# java help for converting temperture

Tags: java

*so if any one can help i am not sure whats wrong i think i need a while state meant 
it keeps giving me an error on the else statement *

```
import java.util.*; //for class Scanner
    public class Tempconversion 
    {
       public static void main(String[] args){
       Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

       double F = 0;
       double C = 0;
       int ConvertFer = 0;
       int ConvertCel = 1;
       int Done = 3;
          System.out.println("Welcome to the Temperature Converter!\n" +
                            "Enter 0 to convert F --> C and 1 to convert from C --> F.\n" +
                            "Enter 3 when done");

        if (ConvertFer == 0)
          System.out.println("Welcome to the F --> C Converter\n"+
                             "Enter Values to convert:");
          C =  reader.nextDouble();
          F = ((F - 32)*5)/9;
          System.out.println(F + "F = " + C + "C.");


        else 
          System.out.println("Welcome to the C --> Fconverter\n"+
                             "Enter Values to convert:"); 

          F = reader.nextdouble();
          C = ((C * 90)/5))+32; 
          System.out.println(C + "C =" + F +"F.");

       } 
       }
```

Comment: What's the error? Also, you probably need braces around the multiple statements you want to execute for the `if` branch and also for the `else` branch.

Comment: what error does it gives you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    double tF = 0.0001;
    double tC = 0.0001;          
    int convertFer = 0;
    int convertCel = 1;

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Temperature Converter!\n"
            + "Enter 0 to convert F --> C and 1 to convert from C --> F.\n"
            + "Enter Control-Z when done!");

    convertFer = reader.nextInt();

    if (convertFer == 0) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the F --> C Converter!\n" + "Enter Values to convert:");
        while (reader.hasNext()){ 

        tC = reader.nextDouble();

        tF = ((tC - 32) * 5) / 9;
           System.out.println(tC +" F = " + tF + " C");}

     } else {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the C --> F Converter!\n" + "Enter Values to convert:");
        while (reader.hasNext()){

        tF = reader.nextDouble();

        tC = ((tF * 9) / 5) + 32;
           System.out.println(tF + "C = " + tC + " F");}

        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        System.exit(0);     
     }     
 }
```

Comment: thats the code i used and so far it is working o refection both answer were good just had to modify to make it work as i wanted it to

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing curly brackets around your `if/else` statements

```
    if (ConvertFer == 0) {
      // convert to F

    }
    else { 
     // convert to C
    }
```

Also, you should read user choice before the `if/else` statements. You might also want to loop your code so you can do this conversion multiple times

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

   double F = 0;
   double C = 0;
   int ConvertFer = 0;
   int ConvertCel = 1;
   int Done = 3;
   System.out.println("Welcome to the Temperature Converter!\n" +
                        "Enter 0 to convert F --> C and 1 to convert from C --> F.\n" +
                        "Enter 3 when done");

  int userChoice = -1;
  while(true) {
      userChoice = reader.nextInt();  // read user choice
      if(userChoice == ConvertFer) {
          // convert to F
      } else if(userChoice == ConvertCel) {
          // convert to C
      } else if (userChoice == Done) {
          break; // finish the loop
      } else {
          System.out.println("Please enter a valid choice");
      }
  }
}
```

**Note** You also shouldn't capitalize your variables by convention so they can be easily differentiated from classes. You should rename your variables to `convertFer`, `convertCel` and `done`

Comment: Tempconversion.java:27: error: 'else' without 'if'
i keep getting that with thebracket

Comment: @LuisOrt You are getting that error because you have some code between `}` that ends the `if` statement and `else` statement. You cannot have any code there. Look at my edit for how you should solve this

Comment: dude thanks honestly i am just staring to learn, i had no idea you can't have code there.

Comment: one question tho why is userChoice = -1

Comment: no particular reason, you don't really have to do it, it just good for debugging purposes to have your variables initialized to some error value. Since you only use 1, 2, 3 in your program logic, I thought -1 wound be an appropriate initialization.